# How do you respond to reviews on the G Suite Marketplace?

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I have an Add-on currently listed in the G Suite Marketplace: https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/extensis_fonts/568288816452

Up until a couple of days ago, the Add-on was listed in the Chrome store as well. I understand that Google was no longer going to be including Docs Add-ons in the Chrome store so that was not a surprise.

However, the Marketplace listing has a note that says "Please visit the Chrome Web Store if you would like to enter a review for this app." The note includes a link back to the URL for the listing in the Chrome store which redirects to the home page of the G Suite Marketplace. Up until the point the Chrome Store listing disappeared, I was able to respond to User reviews in the Chrome store. There appears to be no way to do the same in the Marketplace.

1) How can users Review and comment on the Add-on in the Marketplace?

2) How can I as the developer, respond to comments/reviews?

Comment: Please read [tour] and [ask].  This is a site for programming questions not vendor support, so you'll need to search the web for answers.

Answer (score 1):

The Chrome Web Store listing should not redirect to the G Suite Marketplace listing yet. A fix has already been submitted and will be rolled out soon. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: This is also preventing new users from installing our Docs add-on. Docs add-ons installed through the G Suite Marketplace simply don't show up in the add-ons menu dropdown.

Comment: That shouldn't happen. Can you tell me the GSM app id of you add-on (the number at the end of the URL), please?

Comment: This is problem with unlisted apps that will be fixed by the Chrome Web Store to G Suite Marketplace migration we are working on. In the meantime your CWS listing no longer redirects to GSM: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clearscope/mjfjhbaanghfahcchckpejnocpbppbcc